# Securely tunnel port through intermediate host

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I'm looking to route a port for VNC back to my house here. I have to jump over a single host to then hop to my actual work machine.

- `sittinghere` will be my local home machine
- `hopper` will by the intermediate hop I need to make
- `overthere` will be the remote work machine

I can do this to SSH into my work machine:

```
ssh -t hopper "ssh -t overthere"
```

I'd like to use port forwarding to forward remote port 5900 on `overthere` to local port 5900 on `sittinghere`. However, I'd prefer to be able to do it without binding to a port openly on `hopper` as anyone on that machine would be able to attach to my VNC connection.

Is there any way for me to forward that port to my local machine securely with no one being able to get access to it on `hopper`?

Comment: What VNC client are you using?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ended up using some SSH `~/.ssh/config` hacks to make this happen:

```
Host hopper
    User naftuli
    ForwardAgent yes

Host overthere
    User naftuli
    ForwardAgent yes
    ProxyCommand ssh -q hopper nc overthere 22
```

What this does is that when I attempt to connect to `ssh overthere` from `sittinghere`, it connects to `hopper` and then proxies the SSH connection to port 22 on `overthere` (ie: SSH on `overthere`).

This has some awesome side-effects:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 overthere "x11vnc -display :0 -localhost"
```

Everything works awesome and as far as I can tell, 5900 isn't opened on `hopper`, only forwarded directly from `overthere` to `sittinghere`.

Comment: Incidentally, I should have asked this in the comments before but the solution you stumbled into is right out of the x11nvc man page 8-). Sorry I didn't think to ask what VNC server you were using.

Comment: This scares the bejeezus out of me, but it definitely works!

Comment: In some Linux distros (e.g. Ubuntu 14.04) netcat-openbsd is installed by default. In this case this hack may not work. To fix this problem you should firstly install netcat-traditional package (`apt-get install netcat-traditional -y`). Then you should to explicitly specify the `nc` type in the config file (by replacing `nc` with `nc.traditional`).

Comment: @Naftuli:  Awesome indeed!

Comment: What is `nc` in `ProxyCommand`?

Comment: @AlexanderPozdneev [netcat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc).

Answer (score 28):

Using SSH's native ability to forward ports.  From `sittinghere` execute:

```
 ssh -v -N -L 5900:overthere:5900 user@hopper
```

Point your VNC client to `localhost:5900` and the traffic will be tunneled to `overthere:5900` through the SSH connection established on `hopper`

Comment: AFAIK, this solution won't help you if 5900 is only bound on the local (127.0.0.1) interface, as the tunnel happens to `hopper`, and then `hopper` forwards all traffic to `overthere:5900`. If `overthere:5900` is listening at `0.0.0.0` or the given interface, then it'll work, but not if it's listening at `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward a port from `sittinghere` to `overthere`'s SSH port through `hopper`. Then you can use that port to reach `overthere` directly from `sittinghere`. In this second SSH session you can forward VNC or whatever other ports you like while `hopper` sees only an encrypted SSH session.

First SSH session:

```
ssh -f -N -L 7022:overthere:22 hopper
```

Now tell the SSH client how it can reach `overthere` by adding this config to `~/.ssh/config` on `sittinghere`

```
Host overthere
    HostName hopper
    Port 7022
    HostKeyAlias overthere
```

Second SSH session:

```
ssh -f -N -L 5900:localhost:5900 overthere
```

Or just a regular interactive SSH session without the VNC port tunnel:

```
ssh overthere
```

If you don't want to bother adding lines to `~/.ssh/config` you can still tell it how to connect to `overthere` from the command line:

```
ssh -p 7022 hopper
```

...but without the `HostKeyAlias` SSH will not verify `overthere`'s key fingerprint correctly.

All command lines are to be run from `sittinghere`.

Incidentally, I think you probably don't need to be using `ssh`'s `-t` option.

Answer (score 1):

First connect hopper while making tunnel between worker and home pc.

```
ssh -f ismail@hopper -L 2222:overthere:22 -N
```

then make ssh ro overthere with vnc tunnel

```
ssh -p 2222 -f ismail@localhost -L 5900:localhost:5900
```

Now you can connect with vnc. By the way change configuration of vnc to listen localhost

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the VNC client `vncviewer` from the command line you can use the `-via` switch to tell it to tunnel through a `user@host` prior to connecting to some other host's VNC server.

#### Example

```
$ vncviewer -via user@host localhost:0
```

You can also use `vinagre` to connect via a SSH tunnel like so through the GUI. To do so set your connection up similar to this via the connection dialog in `vinagre`:

[image: ss #1]

Which will result in your connection coming up, tunneled through the SSH tunnel host.

[image: ss #2]

#### References

- [Use VNC? Encrypt It Via SSH](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/06/12/use-vnc-encrypt-it-via-ssh/)

Answer (score 0):

Following command also should work perfectly

```
ssh -f -N -J hopper overthere -L 5900:localhost:5900
```

It was tested with additional parameter to connect PostgreSQL server on `postgres-server` at customised port (`-p` switch) and also with using customised username.

```
ssh -f -N -J user1@jumphost -p 2222 user2@postgres-server -L 5432:localhost:5432
```

As you can see that solution is simple and doesn't require any configuration changes of ssh or any intermediate steps.